# Airflow ExternalTaskSensor don't fail when External Task fails

Tags: python, airflow

I was trying to use the `ExternalTaskSensor` in Airflow 1.10.11 to manage the coordinate some dags. I have develop this code to test the functionality:

```py
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pprint import pprint

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dagrun_operator import TriggerDagRunOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.sensors.external_task_sensor import ExternalTaskSensor
from airflow.utils.state import State

sensors_dag = DAG(
    "test_launch_sensors",
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2020, 2, 14, 0, 0, 0),
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=150),
    tags=["DEMO"],
)

dummy_dag = DAG(
    "test_dummy_dag",
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2020, 2, 14, 0, 0, 0),
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=150),
    tags=["DEMO"],
)


def print_context(ds, **context):
    pprint(context['conf'])


with dummy_dag:
    starts = DummyOperator(task_id="starts", dag=dummy_dag)
    empty = PythonOperator(
        task_id="empty",
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=print_context,
        dag=dummy_dag,
    )
    ends = DummyOperator(task_id="ends", dag=dummy_dag)

    starts >> empty >> ends

with sensors_dag:
    trigger = TriggerDagRunOperator(
        task_id=f"trigger_{dummy_dag.dag_id}",
        trigger_dag_id=dummy_dag.dag_id,
        conf={"key": "value"},
        execution_date="{{ execution_date }}",
    )
    sensor = ExternalTaskSensor(
        task_id="wait_for_dag",
        external_dag_id=dummy_dag.dag_id,
        external_task_id="ends",
        failed_states=["failed", "upstream_failed"],
        poke_interval=5,
        timeout=120,
    )
    trigger >> sensor
```

The idea is that one dag triggers another one with a `TriggerDagRunOperator`. This sets the `execution_date` to the same value in both dags. This works perfectly when the state of the `dummy_dag` last task, `ends`, is `success`.

However, if I force the intermediate task to fail like so:

```py
def print_context(ds, **context):
    pprint(context['conf'])
    raise Exception('ouch')
```

The Sensor doesn't detect the `failed` or the `upstream_failed` states, and it keeps running until it times out. I was using the `failed_states` parameter to indicate which states need to be consider as failure, but it seems that is not working.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`failed_states` was added in Airflow 2.0; you'd set it to `["failed"]` to configure the sensor to fail the current DAG run if the monitored DAG run failed. If given a task ID, it'll monitor the task state, otherwise it monitors DAG run state.

In Airflow 1.x, unfortunately, the `ExternalTaskSensor` operation only compares DAG run or task state against `allowed_states`; as soon as the monitored DAG run or task reaches one of the allowed states, the sensor stops, and is then always marked as successful. By default, the sensor only looks for the `SUCCESS` state, so without a timeout it'll just keep on poking forever if the monitored DAG run has failed. If you put `failed` in the `allowed_states` list, it will still only ever mark itself as successful.

While you could use a timeout, like you I needed the sensor to *fail* it's own DAG run if the external DAG run failed, as if the dependencies for the next task have not been met. This requires you write your own sensor, unfortunately.

Here is my implementation; it is a simplified version of the `ExternalTaskSensor()` class, adapted to my simpler needs (no need to check for a specific task id or for anything other than the same execution date):

```py
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowFailException
from airflow.models import DagRun
from airflow.sensors.base_sensor_operator import BaseSensorOperator
from airflow.utils.db import provide_session
from airflow.utils.decorators import apply_defaults
from airflow.utils.state import State

class ExternalDagrunSensor(BaseSensorOperator):
    """
    Waits for a different DAG to complete; if the dagrun has failed, this
    task fails itself as well.

    :param external_dag_id: The dag_id that contains the task you want to
        wait for
    :type external_dag_id: str
    """

    template_fields = ["external_dag_id"]
    ui_color = "#19647e"

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self, external_dag_id, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.external_dag_id = external_dag_id

    @provide_session
    def poke(self, context, session=None):
        dag_id, execution_date = self.external_dag_id, context["execution_date"]
        self.log.info("Poking for %s on %s ... ", dag_id, execution_date)

        state = (
            session.query(DagRun.state)
            .filter(
                DagRun.dag_id == dag_id,
                DagRun.execution_date == execution_date,
                DagRun.state.in_((State.SUCCESS, State.FAILED)),
            )
            .scalar()
        )
        if state == State.FAILED:
            raise AirflowFailException(
                f"The external DAG run {dag_id} {execution_date} has failed"
            )
        return state is not None
```

The base sensor implementation will call the `poke()` method repeatedly until it returns `True` (or the optional timeout was reached), and by raising `AirflowFailException` the task state is set to *failed* immediately, no retrying. It is then up to the downstream task configuration if they will be scheduled to run.

Comment: Hi you are assuming the target dag to have the same execution_date as your dag, why not extending the ExternalTaskSensor itself and have the same functionality (regarding execution_date, timedelta; etc)

Comment: @AlejandroKaspar: because the existing `ExternalTaskSensor` implementation doesn't lend itself to extending; you'd end up with redundant queries. I specifically simplified the implementation here to suit our much simpler needs; extra code is extra complexity that requires testing and maintenance, and I rather spend my efforts elsewhere.

Comment: @AlejandroKaspar: I note that your implementation doesn't reuse the `ExternalTaskSensor` class either, by the way ;-)

Comment: Yes you are right there, i was just thinking wether that class could be extended or not

Comment: A minor error in the code `self.log.info("Poking for %s.%s on %s ... ", dag_id, execution_date)` has an extra `%s`. It just generates a warning in the logs, but it's working perfectly

Comment: @DiegoRodríguez: thanks for pointing that out, now fixed. There was another reference to the removed `task_id` that I also fixed. I further cleaned up the answer to make it explicit that this only applies to Airflow 1.x.

Answer (score 1):

ExternalTaskSensor just pokes till some expected state is reached, it's state is not intended to be mapped with the external task state.

it defaults to [State.SUCCESS] that's why if success you don't have any problem.
Adding allowed_states=[State.SUCCESS, State.failed, State.upstream_failed]
To your code will at least ensure the external task has finished.

Additionally you can set a timeout to make it fail, if soft_fail = False

If you want for the sensor to FAIL if the external task failed you'll need to write your own implementation of such sensor.

For example here's how I'm checking for Last Dagrun of a Dag to match certain state

```
@provide_session
def poke(self, context, session=None):
    """
    Checks if latest dag_run State is in expected state else keeps polling...
    :param context:
    :param session:
    :return:
    """
    DR = DagRun
    self.log.info(
        f"Poking for {self.external_dag_id}, {self.allowed_states} -> {self.state_condition} ... "
    )
    # If state is expected to match
    if self.state_condition:
        query = session.query(DR).filter(DR.dag_id == self.external_dag_id,
                                                   DR.state.notin_(self.allowed_states))
    # If state is not expected to match
    else:
        query = session.query(DR).filter(DR.dag_id == self.external_dag_id,
                                                   DR.state.in_(self.allowed_states))
    # Filter by last_dagrun, could be max(execution_date) also but avoiding such aggregation
    # by sorting dag_run chronologically in descendent order
    query = query.order_by(DR.execution_date.desc()).first()
    session.commit()
    return not query
```

Comment: Really disappointed with the current behaviour of the Sensor then. I hope they can include this functionality in future versions. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I felt the same, all are very common use cases

Comment: This doesn't actually mark the task as failed.I don't know why you are ordering your query, by the way; you make no use of the value of `query`. And instead of `if query: return False`, why not just use `return not query`?

Comment: As I stated, just added the code as a reference not as a solution itself, yes in deed return not query will be much more cleaner and concise thanks for bringing that up @pablojv, please see Martiijn's answer below with the implementation you needed

Comment: Additionally Martijn's answer is a direct anser to your question